# How can it be determined if a jq selector succeeds or fails, given null or false might be a valid result?

Tags: bash, jq

For a given selector to `jq`, I want to know if the selector succeeds or fails given its input.  For example, the following correctly indicates an error status:

```
% jq -re .bad <<<'{}'
null
% echo $?
1
%
```

However, the following incorrectly indicates an error status (as far as my needs go):

```
% jq -re .key <<<'{"key":false}'
false
% echo $?
1
%
```

The problem with the above is that the -e option will give a return status of 1 if the last output value was either `false` or `null`. However, if values of false and null are present in the JSON input, then this return status gives the wrong impression that some failure occurred.

Am I compelled, in the case of a return code 1, to then check to see if the key is present?  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

Result=$(jq -re .key <<<'{"key":false}')
Status=$?
if [[ $Status -eq 1 ]] ; then
   jq -re '. | has("key")' <<<'{"key":false}' && (exit 0) || (exit 1)
else
   (exit $Status)
fi

# At this point $? can be relied on to indicate success/failure
```

The above solution would change the return status of 1 to 0 and is acceptable for simple jq selectors, but this solution is not satisfactory for computational selectors that might generate a valid result of false or null.

So, is there any approach to know whether a jq selector really succeeds or fails (even for computational selectors), considering that results such as `false` and `null` may be either valid or invalid depending on the selector and input

The solution should be done in Bash 4.2 or later.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me what it is you are trying to
do, but I have the impression that you are going about it the wrong way.
Part of the problem may be the result of terminological issues.
To avoid them, I will adopt terminology that is appropriate to JSON and jq.

Let me point out firstly that in jq, expressions such as `{} | .a` are not regarded as erroneous. If you want an error condition to be raised when an attempt to access the value of a non-existent key is made,
you could write something like:

```
if has("a") then .a else error("no such key") end
```

Another way to distinguish between the case when an input object has a key and the case when it does not have the key
is to write something like:

```
if has("a") then .a else empty end
```

or more compactly:

```
select(has("a")) | .a
```

You can use this technique in conjunction with the -c option of jq as illustrated by the following bash assignments:

```
result=$(jq -c 'select(has("a")) | .a' INPUT.json)
n=$(wc -l <<< "$result")
```

You can then check the value of $n.

Comment: In the general case, the filter is not just a simple key, but might be computational. For example, `jq -r --arg Name $(whoami) '.[]|select(.user == $Name)|.value' <<<'[{"user":"steve", "value":false},{"user":"tom", "value":true}]'`. If the logged-in user is `steve`, then the successful result is `false` and the return code should be 0. If the logged-in user is `mary`, then the return code should NOT be 0. Note that in the above code, in all cases, the return code is 0. This is the problem.

Comment: When using `-re`, with user `steve`, I get output `false` and exit status `1`. With user `mary`, I get no output and exit status `4`, as described in the manual under `-e / --exit-status`. Does that not meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I think this filter will work:

```
map(select(.user==$Name and .value==true))[0] or error($Name)
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in steve tom mary; do
    echo '[{"user":"steve", "value":false},{"user":"tom", "value":true}]' \
    | jq -M -r --arg Name $i 'map(select(.user==$Name and .value==true))[0] or error($Name)' 
    echo $i $?
done
```

Output:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): steve
steve 5
true
tom 0
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): mary
mary 5
```

So in the case of `steve` and `mary` jq returns non-zero exit status and in the case of `tom` it returns zero exit status.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that it's only dependent on the last result of the filter. So it might be easier to add the check as part of your filter at the end.  You just have to remember to ignore the last result.

```
$ jq -re --arg key 'key' '.[$key], has($key)' <<< '{"key":false}'
false
true
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the selector being a key is not the case I've put in the question. And, I've already posted a solution for that case that does not require additional parsing. With computational selectors (non-key selectors), the process isn't as simple. What I would hope for, eventually, is a jq option that truly indicates the error status. I'm thinking now that a workaround/solution for the moment needs to be a combination that separately handles the simple selector case else the computational selector.